# SQLException : Login Failed for user "xx" when using SQLHelper ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem when using the `SQLHelper` class to execute an update stored procedure. I am using `SqlTransaction` as parameters in `SQLHelper.ExecuteNonQuery`.

This is my code :

```
// Create SQLTransaction
public bool Delete()
{
    SqlConnection oConn = tsoDAL.OpenConnection();
    SqlTransaction oTrans = oConn.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        if (Delete(oTrans))
        {
            oTrans.Commit();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            oTrans.Rollback();
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        oTrans.Rollback();
        throw (ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        tsoDAL.CloseConnection(ref oConn);
    }
}

// Call SQLHelper
public bool Delete(SqlTransaction p_oTrans)
{
        try
        {
            SqlParameter[] oParams = new SqlParameter[1];
            oParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@p_iSalesSoId", m_iSalesSoId);

            int iRowAffected = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(p_oTrans, "uspTSO_DeleteSalesOrder",oParams);

            return iRowAffected >= 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
 }
```

The code throws an error when it reaches this code in `SQLHelper.cs`:

```
private static SqlParameter[] DiscoverSpParameterSet(string connectionString, string spName, bool includeReturnValueParameter)
{
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName,cn))
        {
            cn.Open();   // error happens here
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

            if (!includeReturnValueParameter) 
            {
                cmd.Parameters.RemoveAt(0);
            }

            SqlParameter[] discoveredParameters = new SqlParameter[cmd.Parameters.Count];;

            cmd.Parameters.CopyTo(discoveredParameters, 0);

            return discoveredParameters;
        }
    }
```

Error that's shown is

> Login Failed for User 'sa'.

I was searching for the solution for this problem, and I still didn't get the solution that can fix my problem.

I need your help, thank you

Comment: So, is the password correct? Can the `sa` user log in?

Comment: Have your user the right permission on the database?

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes, sa user can login to DBMS

Comment: This is a *very* clear message - you used the wrong password. Please don't just dump some code to get around the "post the code" rule. Post only the parts that are revelant. In this case only the connection string matters and only you can check whether the password contained is correct

Comment: @Flatlineato how to check that permission ?

Comment: @HandaruEriPramudiya *check the password*!. The `sa` account is the administrator, it has *all* permissions. The error says that the login failed, *not* that any permission was denied. Does the connection string even have a `Password` property? Is it correct? Did you use the *same* password to connect with SSMS as you did in the connection string?

Comment: Try to login from managment studio. After check if you user is assigned to the databse and have at least data read permision

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry for breaking the rules. I have select function too and use same connectionstring and that no problems, just in this function i get this SQLException. Password in my connectionstring is correct.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, i use same password. my connectionstring have password property. This is my connectionstring
`<connectionStrings>
    <add 
      name="tsoConnectionString" 
      connectionString="server=PFS-MERABU003\SQL2K8;database=TSO;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;Trusted_Connection=False;" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: I hope this isn't the real password.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hahaha, yeah thats not the real password. Sir, is my connectionstring correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I have trace the problems and the really problem is SQLTransaction Connectionstring lost it password. So in my connectionstring i added
`Persist Security Info=true;` and thats solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: The connection string doesn't lose passwords. Did you *copy* that connection string from some other class *instead* of reading it from the config file? That's the only case where `Persist Security Info=true` would have any effect.